# Unit testing completion blocks in iOS

Tags: ios, unit-testing

I am trying to figure out how to write unit test for client backend code but I have not been successful so far. I am not so experience with unit testing so I read [This](http://www.objc.io/issue-15/), [This](http://blog.dadabeatnik.com/2014/07/13/asynchronous-unit-testing-in-xcode-6/), [andThis](https://pragprog.com/magazines/2012-01/unit-tests-are-first)

and read some similar questions to what I am asking, but I have not been completely figure out how I should be writing unit tests for the client backend.

```
- (void)testThatItGetsAllUsers
{
    // given
    XCTestExpectation *expectation = [self expectationWithDescription:@" fetch all users"];

    // when
    [[Backend sharedInstance] getAllUsers:^(NSArray * arr) {

            XCTAssertNotNil(arr);
            [expectation fulfill];

    }andFailure:^(NSError * err) {
        XCTAssert((err != nil), @"get all users request failed with error:\t%@", err);

    }];

    [self waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:5 handler:^(NSError *error) {
     // request not successfull
        XCTAssert((error != nil), @"get all users from server did not return any data:\t%@", error);
    }];
    // then
}
```

It would be really helpful if someone can point out what I am doing wrong and any additional knowledge is appreciated!

Comment: could you be more specific pls

Comment: @James03, my test above fails, even though I verified that I am getting data with from the server. I am not sure why my unit test fails, thats what  I need help with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify **waitForExpectationsWithTimeout** as follow

```
[self waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:INT16_MAX handler:^(NSError *error) {

    BOOL flag = (error == nil);
    XCTAssert(flag, @"get all users from server did not return any data:\t%@", error);
}];
```

And also add to your **andFailure** block **[expectation fulfill]** like this:

```
andFailure:^(NSError * err) {
    [expectation fulfill];
    XCTAssert((err != nil), @"get all users request failed with error:\t%@", err);
}];
```

If you want to know more about async testing take a look at nshipster [blog](http://nshipster.com/xctestcase/). There is a nice explanation of XCTestExpectation along with example.

By following one of [John Reid](http://qualitycoding.org/) videos I have wrote small [project](https://github.com/salabaha/TestNetworking) which uses **Mocking** and **DI** technics to test networking calls.

Comment: I think there should be err == nil in the assert, because we wants here to check if there is no error.